# Python Tkinter: Changing other button's text from event handler of one button

Tags: python, button, widget, tkinter

I have the following problem when using tkinter to create a very simple window containing a matrix of buttons: When one of the buttons is clicked, the event handler changes the text of that button using the configure method on the button widget. This works. But I also want to change the text in one of the other buttons, which does not work. The method I use is that on creating the button, I store the object returned by the Button method before I use the grid geometry manager to place it. This object looks like ".123456789L" when printed and seems to be a pointer to the widget. I also use configure on this to change the button text. But somehow it seems to be wrong, because it works sometimes, and most of the times not. There's unfortunately no error message, just nothing happens when calling configure. I checked and it seems to be the correct pointer to the widget. Do I have to use a special way to affect a widget other that the one that called the event handler? These are the relevant parts of the code:

```
# CREATING THE BUTTONS:
buttons={} # global
for i in range(3):
 for j in range(3):
  button = Tkinter.Button(self,text='foo')
  buttons[button]=(i,j)
  button.grid(column=j,row=i)
  button.bind( "<Button-1>", self.OnButtonClick )

# CHANGING BUTTONS:
def find_button(i,j):
 """Return the pointer to the other button to be changed when a button has been clicked."""
 for button,key in buttons.items():
  if key==(i,j): return button

def OnButtonClick(self,event):
 print "You clicked the button",buttons[event.widget]
 i,j=buttons[event.widget]
 old_button=find_button(i,j) # This is simplified, I don't actually pass i,j, but other values. But I checked this and it returns the reference to the correct button. But this simplified version works the same way, just assume a different button that the one pressed would be returned.
 old_button.configure(text = 'blabla') # THIS DOES NOT WORK
 event.widget.configure(text = 'something') # THIS WORKS
```

Comment: Unless your full code is more than a hundred lines or so, it would be easier if you just posted the whole thing.  I don't immediately see anything wrong here, which leads me to suspect that the problem is in the part of the code that you did not post.  One thought is to try adding `root.update_idletasks()` after your call to `configure`, where `root` is a reference to your root window widget, but I wouldn't bet on it without seeing the rest of your code.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem and i solve it with:

```
buttons[button]=(i,j,button)
```

and in the function OnButtonClicK:

```
i,j,old_button=buttons[event.widget]

old_button.configure(text = 'blabla') # THIS DOES NOT WORK
```